# How to save and maintain local copy of javascript file using PHP (with parallelism in mind)?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, caching

What I'm after is a PHP-script which will provide a local copy of a javascript file stored on a different domain, e.g. JS-files used for tracking purposes, such as Google Analytics or, in my case, Wordpress Stats.

The intention is to add it as follows in my own :

```
 mysite.com/somepath/wpstats.js.php?w=201145
```

(where "w=year-week_number" is used in the same way as by wordpress.com. Their cache expiry for there original stats JS-file is one year - hence the JS-file will never be changed more often than once a week)

In my `wpstats.js.php` I want to download the correct file from wordpress.com when w=xx changes, otherwise I want to return it from a locally kept copy.

I can implement it with one internal variable called "w_current", so that when a new visitor enters the site the second week `w != w_current` and it will trigger a new fetch. The problem is: **how do I prevent race-conditions/parallelism problems that might occur when two website visitors simultaneously loads the website the first time the second week [1]?**

[1] both apache-processes evaluate the `w != w_current` and starts two downloads of the (potentially) new version of the wpstats.js-file and both try to write it to the local copy (e.g. `own_wpstats.js`) which wpstats.js.php (in the normal case where a local copy already exists) will include:

```
if ($_GET["w"] == w_current) require("own_wpstats.js");
```

The main reason for doing this (performance possibly being another) is due to the fact that Wordpress.com Stats injects (via DOM) an additional JS-tracking file from a third party, quantserve.com. In my locally kept "WP JS file" I will make sure this quantserve.com thing is excluded, but this is a separate programming challenge than the question I try to ask here. A search for "quantserve.com tracking cookie" gives many discomfortable results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't worry **TOO much** about such a race condition. "Worst case" is you download the file twice.

But IF you are going to be doing ANY tracking of these files in a DB, then preventing the double download would be simple. Immediately before you start the download, check DB if file needs a refresh, log the refresh to the DB, and THEN do the download. Give the file a unique primary-key (site_url + file_name) and the second check before update will fail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's not so much the multiple downloads, more so the duplicate editing (partially done manually, since I want to review the "new" edited version before it is used). I had actually though about using a DB table as you describe and, by using transactions, I agree I should be able to make a "safe" implementation. For simplicity, and potential use for other similar situations, I think I'll stick to the files-only solution for now - ignoring the fact that the admin, in some rare occasions, might be notified twice/multiple times of a pending new file.

Comment: Any specific reason to do a manual review? If you know in advance that you are looking to exclude very specific things, then create a dummy version of that file and just modify the included src/path, which you're doing anyway. This way manual intervention will only be required whenever quantserve changes THEIR file.